# tightvncserver not setting up properly during installation using apt-get

Tags: pi-3, ssh, linux, vnc, kali

I am trying to use `tightvncserver` on my Raspberry Pi 3 so that I can access the GUI without a monitor and keyboard.

However, the install isn't `updating-alternatives` to `vncserver` in `/usr/bin/` directory. There should be a file in that directory named, `tightvncserver` after install, but that does not occur in my install as seen below.

When I install `tightvncserver` and then try to find `tightvncserver`, `which tightvncserver` the pi does not find the tool in `/usr/bin/`. However, before I even installed `tightvncserver` I had `/usr/bin/vncserver`.

[image: can't find tightvncserver]

When I ran `vncserver` it ran `tigervncserver`, which proves that it the setup process did not complete properly because during the setup process the system is supposed to `update-alternatives` to use `/usr/bin/tightvncserver` as `/usr/bin/vncserver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that `TightVNC` isn't part of this image of Kali Linux.

`TigerVNC` is a fork that is supported by the standard Kali Linux repositories.

I managed to figure out a pretty good alternative to `TightVNC` and `TigerVNC`. Below is my expanded solution.

### Solution:

I would recommend using `x11vnc` as it provides the actual desktop experience rather than a virtual one.

To install `x11vnc` enter the following command:

`apt-get update && apt-get install -y x11vnc`

If you experience that the `framebuffer` size is too small, then to change it do the following:

1. Locate `/boot/config.txt` and open it using `nano` or `vim`

(**Note**: If the file `/boot/config.txt` does not exist, safely power-off the Pi using the command, `poweroff` and take the Micro-SD card out and plug it into a laptop or desktop computer. When the Micro-SD card mounts, open it. The `config.txt` file should be on the root of the mounted Micro-SD card).

2. uncomment the following text in `config.txt`:

*Before*:

`#framebuffer_width=1280`

`#framebuffer_height=720`

*After*:

`framebuffer_width=1280`

`framebuffer_height=720`

3. Save and exit the file. Then, reboot the Pi and start `x11vnc` by using the following command to push it into a background process: `x11vnc -usepw -reopen -bg -forever &`

---

If you would like to start `x11vnc` at boot, add the following to a file called `x11vnc.desktop` in `~/.config/autostart`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=x11vnc
Exec=x11vnc -usepw -reopen -bg -forever &
Comment=Starts an x11vnc server on port kali:5900
```

(**Note**: If `~/.config/autostart` does not exist, create the `autostart` directory by issuing the following command: `mkdir ~/.config/autostart`).

See [how-to-execute-shell-script-on-kali-linux-startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276463/how-to-execute-shell-script-on-kali-linux-startup) for more information on application autostart on Kali Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The tightvncserver seams to be a drop-in-replacment. After the install process, you could use the tightvncserver with this command:

```
$ vncserver :1
```

For more commandline options look here:
[TightVNC Help](http://www.tightvnc.com/vncserver.1.php)